# R If two conditions are true, change the value of a column

Tags: r

I'm trying to consolidate the following.

```
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "1998"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "1999"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "2000"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "2001"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "2002"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "2003"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "2010"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "2011"] <- "Y"
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & BattingData$yearID == "2012"] <- "Y"
```

I was able to get the criteria portion to work however, I'm having to do one line per year. Any way to consolidate and say if player is this person, change the values in the ped column to "Y" for each of these years?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `BattingData` (paste the results of `dput(BattingData)`?

Comment: I am just using the batting table in the lahman package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) within** Collapse to this single statement:

```
within(BattingData, 
  ped[playerID == "rodrial01" & (yearID %in% c(1998:2003, 2010:2012))] <- "Y")
```

**2) transform/replace** Another approach is:

```
yrs <- c(1998:2003, 2010:2012)
transform(BattingData, 
  ped = replace(ped, playerID == "rodrial01" & (yearID %in% yrs), "Y"))
```

Comment: This will also impact years between 2003 and 2010 and those are not years I want to change to "Y".

Comment: Have modified the vector of years.

Comment: The code works but it shows a tibble output. I want to actually change the value within the BattingData dataframe.

Comment: You assign it back.  `BattingData <- within(...)` or if you want to preserve the input use a different name on the left hand side.

Comment: If you don't mind could you leave both on there for anyone who is just starting with R like myself. The version with one range of years as well as the one with the vector of years.

Comment: If every year were wanted between 1998 and 2012 then replace `c(...)` with `1998:2012` .

Answer (score 1):

you could also convert to int and use *>=*/*<=* as follows:

```
BattingData$ped[BattingData$playerID == "rodrial01" & (strtoi(BattingData$yearID) >= 1998 & strtoi(BattingData$yearID) <= 2012)] <- "Y"
```

I would prefer to change the entire data frame column to *int*